# C++ dll using a method in a dll

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to get a simple c++ program to use a method in a dll. I've been receiving a variety of errors as I've adjusted the code and have been stuck mostly, as in the code posted below, with "undefined reference to" the method. The code below is being compiled as follows.

```
g++ -c testdll.cpp
g++ -shared -o testdll.dll testdll.o
g++ -o test test.cpp -L./ -ltestdll
```

**error**

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -L./ -ltestdll
C:\Users\ROGERF~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cca9YhFn.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined
 reference to `__imp__ZN7TestDLL9writeDataESs'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea why directory C:\Users\ROGERF~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ is involved in the process. That showed up after I started using code from the Microsoft website in the header file. Previously, I was just getting undefined reference to 'writeData'

**testdll.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class TestDLL {
public:
    string data1;

    public: void writeData (string s) {
        printf ("%s \n", s.c_str());
    }
};
```

**TestDLL.h**

```
#ifndef TESTDLL_H
#define TESTDLL_H

#ifdef TRADITIONALDLL_EXPORTS
#define TRADITIONALDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TRADITIONALDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

class TestDLL {
    public:
       std::string data1;

    public:
        TRADITIONALDLL_API void writeData (std::string);
};
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif // TESTDLL_H
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include "TestDLL.h"
using namespace std;
class TestDLL;
int 
main () {
  TestDLL testdll;
  testdll.writeData ("success");
}
```

Extended explanation: I've focused this down to something easy to post and hopefully easy for someone to answer. I was a C programmer back at the dawn of the PC era but haven't done much with C++ ever or C since then. I've been a Java programmer for quite some time (along with web stuff). Right now, I'm dealing with an existing program that can be extended with dlls, and the dlls need to be connected to a system written in Java. I've done the first step in JNI, so I have Java connected to a single dll. But the architecture needs to be:

Existing C application - dll extensions - dll for JNI - Java system

with communication both ways.

Comment: Post the unedited error messages.

Comment: Try renaming testdll.dll to libtestdll.dll

Comment: error message added above

Comment: same error with libtestdll

Comment: It looks like you forgot to use `-DTRADITIONALDLL_EXPORTS` when compiling the DLL.

Comment: g++ -DTRADITIONALDLL_EXPORTS -o test test.cpp -L./ -ltestdll

Comment: g++ -DTRADITIONALDLL_EXPORTS -o test test.cpp -L./ -ltestdll
C:\Users\ROGERF~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cclNTQ9r.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined
 reference to `TestDLL::writeData(std::string)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You should take the habit of compiling with `g++ -Wall -g`. I'm surprized that DLL don't want `-fPIC` (but I never used Windows). On Linux shared libraries want `-fPIC`.

Comment: That's a good idea Basile. (I had to look them up.) Unfortunately, in this case, the error message is the same - no more information.

Comment: Read again. When compiling **the DLL**.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. If you read the extended part (and figure it's getting later where I am so I'm wearing out after a long day with this) .. you might get the mistake. They're both supposed to be dlls (in the real version).

Comment: Got it to run -- see comments under dgnuff's Answer below.

Comment: The two methods of defining that macro have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks. I fought with this all day and it's much better to end with working code. I'm going to sleep better tonight. My guess is that you know the feeling. We all have days like this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you add the two following lines to testdll.cpp:

```
#define TRADITIONALDLL_EXPORTS 1
#include "TestDLL.h"
```

I suspect that what's happening is that you're not doing that, so GCC doesn't know to compile `TestDLL::writeData()` with DLL export linkage.

Comment: g++ -c testdll.cpp
testdll.cpp:7:7: error: redefinition of 'class TestDLL'
 class TestDLL {
       ^
In file included from testdll.cpp:4:0:
TestDLL.h:15:7: error: previous definition of 'class TestDLL'
 class TestDLL {
       ^

Comment: tried it without including TestDLL.h as well (but with #define TRADITIONALDLL_EXPORTS 1) ... gives the same old undefined reference error.

Comment: Try changing this line `public: void writeData (string s) {` to `public: TRADITIONALDLL_API void writeData (string s) {` in testdll.cpp

Comment: Well, fer cryin' out loud. Took a little playing to define TRADITIONALDLL_API (just copy-pasted the if defs from the h file) - but that got it to compile and it runs.